# Android 'Spinning Wheel' application crashes at launch

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, logcat, spinning

I've taken a code from a tutorial about a spinning wheel.
I've adjusted the code to work from my application but it's crashing for some reason and I can't figure out why.

I'll really appreciate any kind of help.

The logcat information is :

```
com.truthordareyakir.android.truthordare E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.truthordareyakir.android.truthordare, PID: 2404
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 37748748 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 27MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:467)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:497)
        at com.truthordareyakir.android.truthordare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to initialise the byte with a lower value ? 
Sometimes the Memory of your phone can't process such high va. lues.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your animated image is too large.  You have have separate sized images for each drawable type?  hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, etc...

Use the Android [Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to scale images if needed.